# Why do axis2 client prompt "An unknown transport called https exists." when using HTTPS?

Tags: java, https, axis

When using my axis client in HTTP, my code works just fine, but as soon as I use an HTTPS endpoint, I get the following stack trace

```
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: An unknown transport called https exists.
    at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferInTransport(ClientUtils.java:119) ~[axis2-kernel.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:183) ~[axis2-kernel.jar:1.5.4]
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165) ~[axis2-kernel.jar:1.5.4]
    at com.vodafone.gdsp.ws.SubmitSMSv2ServiceStub.submitSMSv2(SubmitSMSv2ServiceStub.java:193) ~[vodafonews.jar:?]
    at com.trilliantnetworks.vodafone.services.CallVodafoneServices.submitSMSv2(CallVodafoneServices.java:447) ~[vodafonews.jar:?]
    ... 21 more
```

Here's the HTTP client configuration

```java
HttpClientParams httpClientParams = new HttpClientParams();
httpClientParams.setConnectionManagerTimeout(10000L);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientParams, conMgr);

context.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, client);
context.setProperty(HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, Boolean.TRUE);
context.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTO_RELEASE_CONNECTION, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Here's the code I'm using before making a call

```java
// Enabling auto cleanup & activating asynchronous connection handler
serviceStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setCallTransportCleanup(true);
serviceStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setUseSeparateListener(true);
serviceStub._getServiceClient().engageModule("addressing");

// Executing a cleanup of the connection before using it in case.
serviceStub._getServiceClient().cleanup();
serviceStub._getServiceClient().cleanupTransport();
```

There is not much documentation about this, does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The Axis2 documentation has a page describing how to setup the HTTP-Transport to support HTTPS (https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#httpsupport). Please note that the manual might not exactly match your setup - you are still using Apache-Axis2 version 1.5.4, but the documentation available covers only versions 1.6.1 to 1.8.0

Comment: Yeah, I finally found the complete vanilla axis2.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, there's no descriptor for HTTPS in axis2 configuration. You usually can change it through the code, but for some reason, my version was not working. What you can do is copy the vanilla version of axis2 located in the JAR in your maven repositories which you can open with 7zip. Then in your code, when creating the context, specify the path of the configuration file:

```java
ConfigurationContext context = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(null, "C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\Custom\\axis2.xml");
```

In your configuration replace the section `Transport Outs` by the following

```
<transportSender name="local" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender" />

<transportSender name="http" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender">
    <parameter name="PROTOCOL">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
    <parameter name="Transfer-Encoding">chunked</parameter>

    <!-- If following is set to 'true', optional action part of the 
         Content-Type will not be added to the SOAP 1.2 messages -->
    <!--  <parameter name="OmitSOAP12Action">true</parameter>  -->
</transportSender>

<transportSender name="https" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender">
    <parameter name="PROTOCOL">HTTP/1.1</parameter>
    <parameter name="Transfer-Encoding">chunked</parameter>

    <!-- If following is set to 'true', optional action part of the 
         Content-Type will not be added to the SOAP 1.2 messages -->
    <!--  <parameter name="OmitSOAP12Action">true</parameter>  -->
</transportSender>

<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
    <parameter name="port">8080</parameter>
</transportReceiver>

<transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
    <parameter name="port">8443</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

Which you can find here on [SAP website](https://help.sap.com/viewer/bec74fcf50bf4fcc8b5a3f1ad71e8374/4.2.13/en-US/57a000a86d6d1014b3fc9283b0e91070.html)

Once this configuration is in place, axis2 should be able to find the HTTPS descriptor and the error should go away.

Here's the complete configuration I've used, I'm on axis2 version 1.5.4

[Axis2 full configuration for HTTPS support on multi-threading mode](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2169959)